# formatting PLSQL developer

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Is there any shortcut for formatting the query in `plsql developer`?
I want to format below query:

```
SELECT * FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
```

like:

```
select 
  *
from
  T1, T2
WHERE
  T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: Yes, PL/SQL Developer has a PL/SQL beautifier, which does SQL too. [Find out more](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html). Be aware that it can't handle some rare SQL constructs.

Comment: I'm not sure it can match your example exactly. For one thing, keywords can be set to either uppercase or lowercase, but not uppercase for `WHERE` and lowercase for `select` and `from`, if that is your rule.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am using version 12.0.7.

For this version, function name is not `Edit / PL/SQL Beautifier`

It is `Tools / Source / PL/SQL Beautifier`

It took some time for me to find it. I hope this help others.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

PL/SQL Developer does not have a default keyboard shortcut to launch the PL/SQL Beautifier but it is easy to configure one.

Open Tools --> Preferences, click on "Key Configuration", find the item "Edit / PL/SQL Beautifier", double-click on the empty space, click whatever keys you want to use for the shortcut, then click OK:
[image]

You can also enable the PL/SQL Beautifier to run automatically:
[image]

But be careful before you become too dependent on the code beautifier.  They generally do not work well for Oracle SQL and PL/SQL.  PL/SQL has a huge grammar and no code beautifier in existence can handle all types of code well.  Also, dynamic code is much more important in PL/SQL than in other languages; beautifiers won't help with dynamic code so you'll likely need to manually format some code anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You must select your query and then click PL/SQL Beautifier button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select your code and Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> on SQL Developer and PLSQL Developer as well.

Answer (score 2):

For **Ver. 12.07** you can click `PL/SQL Beautifier` button to format sql

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PL/SQL Beautifier allows you to format your SQL and PL/SQL code through a user-defined set of rules. Your code can automatically be beautified when you compile, save, or open a file.

Comment: I am using sql developer mac os version 18.1.0.0.5

see attach export file.

I dont see beautify for my short cut key mapping 
is this a plug in I need to install ??

[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mgHiGwWmzI8SOccT61TbFnYMgYXGgGySf9Gl3th4TVM/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize PLSQL Beautifier, save your custom file on your PC and then import file and save it as picture below.

[image]